# 3 CUP Broken Dependencies Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: package-management

Totally apologize for not meeting all the standards here.  Been using Ubuntu since Nov 2015 and performed two upgrades I'm still a rookie and have not found the exact problem in any Ubuntu searches.  Here's the 3 broken dependencies listed in the Synaptic Package Manager under broken Dependencies:

1. CUPS  2.1.3-4unbuntu0.2  2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2  Common UNIX Printing System(tm)-PPD/driver, support web interface
2. CUPS-core-drivers  2.1.3-4unbuntu0.2  2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2  Common UNIX Printing System(tm)-PPD-less printing
3. CUPS-Daemon  2.1.3-4  2.1.3  Common UNIX Printing System(tm)-Daemon

This PC is only used at home as a stand-alone and only connected to the IT.  I can still print with no problem, however, since this occurred last week after performing an update.  The only problem this causes the inability to perform any updates, which is a serious problem.

I will provide any info you need, but will need step by step help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in a recent CUPS update: [cups : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4) but 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1676621)

Solution given in [comment 14](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1676621/comments/14) is:

`sudo apt-get install libcups2=2.1.3-4 cups libcupscgi1=2.1.3-4 libcupsimage2=2.1.3-4 libcupsmime1=2.1.3-4 libcupsppdc1=2.1.3-4 cups-core-drivers cups-daemon ghostscript cups-client=2.1.3-4 cups-ppdc cups-filters printer-driver-gutenprint cups-filters`

Comment: Results:   ron@ron-Aspire-X3910:~$ apt-get -f install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
ron@ron-Aspire-X3910:~$

Comment: Not much info there due to space.  I copied terminal cmds and results, but to long to post.  Tried to unlock file and then tried kill cmd and reboot per article https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1853026